# How can I put the 'NIL node' in the red-black tree code?

Tags: python, tree

I need to implement red-blackTree.

I know that every leaf node should be pointed to a node in 'data: NIL / color: Black'

I tried

```
def insert(self, value, tree):
    if tree == None and self.root == None:
        self.root = Node(value, 'B')

        NILnode = Node('NIL', 'B')
        self.root.left = NILnode
        self.root.right = NILnode
        return
```

it failed.

this is my code.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data, color='B', left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.value = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = parent
        self.color = color        

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value.__str__()

class RBT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value, tree):
        if tree == None and self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(value, 'B')
            return

        if tree.value < value:
            if tree.right == None or tree.right.value == 'NIL':
                node = Node(value, 'R')
                tree.right = node
                node.parent = tree
                self.rebuild(node)

            else:
                self.insert(value, tree.right)

        else:
            if tree.left == None or tree.left.value == 'NIL':
                node = Node(value, 'R')
                tree.left = node
                node.parent = tree
                self.rebuild(node)

            else:
                self.insert(value, tree.left)

    def rebuild(self, node):
        while node.parent != None and node.parent.color == 'R':
            parent_sibling = self.get_sibling(node.parent)

            #case-1
            if parent_sibling.color == 'R':
                node.parent.color == 'B'
                parent_sibling.color == 'B'
                node.parent.parent.color == 'R'
                node = node.parent.parent
            else:
                if self.which_child(node.parent) == 'L':
                    #case-2-1
                    if self.which_child(node) == 'R' and self.which_child(node.parent) == 'L':
                        self.rotate_left(node.parent)
                        node = node.left
                    #case-2-2
                    if self.which_child(node) == 'L' and self.which_child(node.parent) == 'L':
                        node.parent.color = 'B'
                        node.parent.parent.color = 'R'
                        self.rotate_right(node.parent.parent)
                else:
                    #case-2-3
                    if self.which_child(node) == 'L' and self.which_child(node.parent) == 'R':
                        self.rotate_right(node.parent)
                        node = node.right
                    #case-2-4
                    if self.which_child(node) == 'R' and self.which_child(node.parent) == 'R':
                        node.parent.color = 'B'
                        node.parent.parent.color = 'R'
                        self.rotate_left(node.parent.parent)
```

I didn't post the last code because it seemed like the rotate()
function had nothing to do with NIL.

How can I put the 'NIL node' in the red-black tree code?

Thank you for reading the long code.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is exactly - you say you failed and that it's not working, but you're not clear about what you expect or need and what you're getting instead. However, your code is obviously wrong, since you create one `Node('NIL', 'B')` node and proceed to point both `.left` and `.right` to the same node - this will never work as expected, unless you imagine using a single 'nil node'. However, I'm wondering why you wouldn't just use `None` to represent the dead end leaf then.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.
As you said, I used None without using NIL, and left and right respectively pointed to each other None.
I think I got what I wanted. Thank you very much.